# Фильтрация пустых строк в массиве на C#, используя LINQ

Tags: linq, c#

Есть массив строк, содержащий пустые и нулевые строки:

```
string[] numbers = {null, "один", "", "два", "", "три", null};
```

Как удалить из него пустые и нулевые строки?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вызов

```
numbers.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).ToArray();
```

вернет исходный массив строк, за исключением пустых и нулевых.